# Array loses content javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, jszip

I have created an upload function that puts the uploaded data in an zip file (with jszip) which works perfectly fine. But when i try to add the content of the files that are uploaded to the jszip folder they are just empty.

Through printing out the array that I want to add the console I saw that for some reason there is no data in the array when it is used in the for loop.

```
var files = filesToRead;
var fragmente_name = [];

for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    fragmente_name.push(f.name);
}
console.log(fragmente_inhalt);
for(var i = 0; i < fragmente_name.length; i++) {
    console.log(fragmente_inhalt[i]);
    if(element == "ambeth_script_upload") {
        script_attachments.file(fragmente_name[i], fragmente_inhalt[i]);
    } else if(element == "folder_upload") {
        watcher_folder.file(fragmente_name[i], fragmente_inhalt[i]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The docs only specify `for` to have 3 arguments, `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])`

Comment: `(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)` 4 arguments?

Comment: @Deda — No. 3. Observe the *comma operator* between `0` and `f`. It is not a semi-colon.

Comment: @NikkoKhresna — There are only three arguments. The initialization expression  just uses a comma operator.

Comment: where does `fragmente_inhalt` come from?, you are not logging the content of `fragmente_name`

Comment: also, where's `element` comming from for that `if` condition?

Comment: but what does `f` do in `var i = 0, f`? it doesnt assign anything to `f`. Then it might assign `undefined` when `fragmente_name.push(f.name);`. Or is there some syntax i have never heard of?

Comment: @arieljuod you can consider fragmente_inhalt and element as given, it is not really important to the question, but they are defined.

Comment: @NikkoKhresna fragmente_name works perfectly fine, just fragmente_inhalt does not work. I have also never heard of that syntax, I found it in another example of JZip, but it works so I wont touch it... :D (thinking about it I guess it initializes the variable)